# Error while import-snapshot VHD file from S3 to EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have a VHD file with Windows OS, that was uploaded into S3, so I'm trying to create an import-snapshot from S3. While trying it I'm getting the below error, by using the below linux command.

> An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the ImportSnapshot operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials

```
aws ec2 import-snapshot --disk-container "Format=VHD,UserBucket={S3Bucket=<s3_bucket_name>,S3Key=<S3_Key_of_vhd_file>}" --output json
```

Also, I have attached below few permissions/policies to the EC2 instance.

S3 Full Access

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

STS Assume Role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

VM Import/Export

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::import-to-ec2-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:ModifySnapshotAttribute",
                "ec2:CopySnapshot",
                "ec2:RegisterImage",
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please suggest, if anything needs to attach more policies/permission.?

Thanks
Rajaganesh